# Maximum call stack size exceeded in Http Interceptor of Angular 4

Tags: spring, angular, rest, angular-http-interceptors

I have `check-session` api which check if the session is still valid. I want to check it in every request which means I would like to call this api before every request in `Http Interceptor` of `Angular 4`.

```
return next.handle(req).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
  const http = this.inj.get(HttpClient);
  http.get('/api/auth/check-session').subscribe(res => {
   console.log('res', res);
  });
```

And on server site it looks like:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/check-session", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public Boolean checkToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
        boolean requestedSessionIdValid = request.isRequestedSessionIdValid();
        return request.isRequestedSessionIdValid();
    }
```

But when I start my app and want to call first api I get error:

```
ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Observable.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:177)
    at Observable.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:160)
```

Does anyone have any clue how can I get rid of this error?

Comment: In an http interceptor, you're sending an http request. So that triggers the interceptor, which sends an http request, which triggers the interceptor, etc. etc. Yu rzally, really don't want to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Ok, so are there any other ways to do above?

Comment: Just don't. It makes no sense to send a "check session" request before each and every request. Why do ou thin it's a reasonable idea? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Ok...so how can I check if the session is still valid or not?

Comment: You don't. You send your request, and if you get an error back informing you that the session is invalid, you ask the user to log in again.

Comment: Another way to look at this - in the instant between asking whether the session is valid, and then sending your actual request, the session could have ended. So you can't really trust the answer anyway. You'll still need to handle the possibility that the session may be invalid when your request arrives. Given that you'll need to handle that case anyway, the initial check is doing nothing for you.